# Chrome console errors - how can I see the time the error occured?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to know when the errors occurred (it's a long-running processs and it may have occurred yesterday or today and that information will help me debug what's going on).

Can I see the time the errors occurred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the DevTools Settings and enable "Show timestamps" in the "Console" section. This setting will show dates for all, old and new, console messages.

---

[image: DevTools settings with "Show timestamps" checked]

---

[image: error message in the DevTools Console with a timestamp]